# Android/Java: Waiting until closure has completed running

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, closures

I'm having trouble with some async programming within an Android application. I have some code in the `ClientLocation` class that gets the user's lat/lon, but once I get them I need to pass them to a function. When stepping through the code I can see that the `repository.getDeals` call is run before the `gotLocation` closure is entered.

Here's the important bit of code:

```
...
this.repository = Repository.getInstance();
ClientLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new ClientLocation.LocationResult() {
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location) {
        userLatitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        userLongitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    }
};
ClientLocation clientLocation = new ClientLocation();
clientLocation.getLocation(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
// I need the latitude and longitude values at this point in order to properly call getDeals
// currently when this is called the userLat/lon values are 0.0 because gotLocation didn't run yet
deals = repository.getDeals(searchQuery, maxDistInKm, userLatitude, userLongitude);
```

What's a pattern where `getDeals` won't be called before `gotLocation` has completed running? New to async programming so any other tips are welcome!

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android), let me know here if you need help :D

Comment: in addition to that, you could also simply consider moving your code (the `repository.getDeals`)  into `gotLocation` so that it would only execute as soon as the location is actually received.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
boolean isFinished  = false

 Thread {

     this.repository = Repository.getInstance();
     ClientLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new 
     ClientLocation.LocationResult() {
     @Override
     public void gotLocation(Location location) {
     userLatitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
     userLongitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
         isFinished = true
     }
   };



    while(true){

      if(isFinished ) break:
    }
   ClientLocation clientLocation = new ClientLocation()
   clientLocation.getLocation(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
    deals = repository.getDeals(searchQuery, maxDistInKm, 
    userLatitude, userLongitude);

    Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

}
```